# Unable to access phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Anyone can help me

unable to access phpMyAdmin → http://34.100.189.79/phpmyadmin/

Regards

Answer (score 0):

> session_write_close(): write failed: No space left on device

The disk on your server is full. Delete files to make space or increase the size of the disk.

Comment: we have used only 2.5 GB out of 10

Comment: Your webserver thinks different. Please provide the output `df -h` and `namei -l /var/lib/php/sessions` on your server (you can edit your question).

Answer (score -2):

What error code is the web server giving you? I mean like "404 - page not found"?

My best guess with what little info I have is, either phpmyadmin is not in your web server's directory tree, or it's not "aliased" in like an Apache config file (if the files are truly not in your web tree).

Comment: The URL is publicly available. Just check it.

Comment: Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

session_write_close(): write failed: No space left on device (28)

session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/sessions)